# DynamoDB unmarshall array of dynamodb records? (SDK v3 javascript)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I can't find a way to unmarshal an array of DynamoDB records? I'm getting multiple items back from my query in DynamoDB, and I can't use the `unmarshal` function that comes from `@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb` on an array of records. When I iterate through the array of records and unmarshal each one, that works, but this is not the best solution since I'm getting back a lot of data. How can I get DynamoDB to return multiple records without iterating through the array of records to unmarshall each one?

Code:

```
  const client = new DynamoDBClient({ region: 'us-east-1' });  
  const currentDateUTC = moment().utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD');

  const command = new QueryCommand({
    TableName: 'Device-Data',
    IndexName: 'timestamp-index',
    KeyConditionExpression: '#timestamp = :timestamp',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#timestamp': 'timestamp' },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':timestamp': { S: currentDateUTC } },
  });
  
  const data = await client.send(command)
```

Response:

```
[
  {
    deviceId: {
      S: "test1",
    },
    userId: {
      S: "318ecd46-bead-440f-83eb-60345aaa1c40",
    },
    timestamp: {
      S: "2022-06-12",
    },
    frequency: {
      S: "Monthly",
    },
  },
  {
    deviceId: {
      S: "test2",
    },
    userId: {
      S: "318ecd46-bead-440f-83eb-60345aaa1c40",
    },
    timestamp: {
      S: "2022-06-12",
    },
    frequency: {
      S: "Monthly",
    },
  },
]
```

Desired Response:

```
[
  {
    deviceId: "test1",
    userId: "318ecd46-bead-440f-83eb-60345aaa1c40",
    timestamp: "2022-06-12",
    frequency: "Monthly",
  },
  {
    deviceId: "test2",
    userId: "318ecd46-bead-440f-83eb-60345aaa1c40",
    timestamp: "2022-06-12",
    frequency: "Monthly",
  },
]
```

Comment: Using the DynamoDB Document Client - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-dynamodb-utilities.html

Answer (score 8):

You can do something like this in v3:

```
const { unmarshall } = require("@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb");

const items = data.Items.map( (item) => {
    return unmarshall(item);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`DynamoDBDocumentClient` is made to automatically unmarshall your data and make it easier to work with in your code.

```
import { DynamoDBClient } from '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb';
import { DynamoDBDocumentClient, QueryCommand } from '@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb';

...

const client = new DynamoDBClient();
const docClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(client);

const command = new QueryCommand({ [config here...] });  
const data = await docClient.send(command);
```

This will give you the Dynamo data as a regular JavaScript object as you'd expect.

Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/classes/_aws_sdk_lib_dynamodb.dynamodbdocumentclient-1.html